# button.value returns "" . Expected - text value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on "rock paper scissors". Earlier in the project button.value used to return it element's text value. Then, I changed something in my code, and wasn't smart enough to commit the last working changes. So now I'm dealing with this. I could've substitude .value with something else, but I just want to figure out what's wrong. Why the value of the "buttons" element I get now is "" and not the text value.

```
       <div id="buttonHolder">
            <button type="submit" id="rock" >Rock</button>
            <button type="submit" id="paper">Paper</button>
            <button type="submit" id="scissors">Scissors</button>
        </div>


**//script**

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");


buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click",() =>{
        let playerSelection = button.value;
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    })
});
```

Comment: Buttons don't have a value they have text. Use `.innerText`

Comment: when I typed in the console button's id .value it used to give me text. Now the return value is "". That's what I'm trying to figure out. What have changed

Comment: example <button type="submit" id="rock" value="rock">Rock</button>

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, your buttons are lacking the `value` attribute. Unless this is present you will have an empty string for `.value`

Comment: Adding to @JonP `.innerHTML` is another option.

Comment: Reading the value through `textContent` might be a better idea here, since we don't want the HTML to be parsed and perhaps cause some overhead. Just a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as pointed out in the comments the button elements didn't have a  set `value` attribute (for which a value wouldn't be worth defining manually anyway in this case), so you couldn't use that in your original implementation.

#### Possible approaches

Here's some properties you could access to get the text contained in an element easily:

- [node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)
- [HTMLElement.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

To know when you should use `HTMLElement.innerText` over `node.textContent` or `HTMLElement.innerHTML`, go [see the differences at the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) - or view this summarization I made:

> textContent gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and
> `<style>` elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable”
> elements. textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast,
> innerText won’t return the text of “hidden” elements and is aware of styling.
>
> Since innerText takes CSS styles into account,
> reading the value of innerText triggers a computationally expensive reflow to ensure up-to-date
> computed styles (this should be avoided when possible).
>
> Differences from
> innerHTML: Element.innerHTML returns HTML as per its name.
> People use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an
> element, but textContent has better performance because its value is
> not parsed as HTML.
>
> Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

*Note: as mentioned, content from the document has been altered for concision.*

Use `node.textContent` (*over `HTMLElement.innerHTML` because the former generally has better performance in retrieving text from an element, for example, since it doesn't parse the HTML*):

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let playerSelection = button.textContent;
    console.log(playerSelection)
    //  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="buttonHolder">
  <button type="submit" id="rock">Rock</button>
  <button type="submit" id="paper">Paper</button>
  <button type="submit" id="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see innerXXX or textContent as a label, a text, not something to represent an object. For example with the id, you can next change the button color or replace text by WIN easily.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by WIN, is it window ?

Comment: Thank you for your time, answering my question. The only thing that remains a mystery  : how is that possible that a day ago (before some changes in my code) i was able to get the output that was inner text itself by using button.value (but not having the "value" attribute in the element itself? Or maybe I'm just going crazy.

Comment: Maybe the button was in a form or something and when submitted the result was displayed somewhere? Or more likely, you might be going mad (or even more likely I'm wrong about both and it's some thing I don't know about).

Comment: lol;) probably.. I should give up thinking about it. Maybe one day the answer comes by itself. Anyway. I used button.textContent and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To use arrow function, whatever the scope, and have the right button object, as your are deeling with events, you can get the event object triggered by the button that contains the clicked button itself. Then you can retreive any attributes you want.

```
   <div id="buttonHolder">
        <button type="submit" id="rock" >Rock</button>
        <button type="submit" id="paper">Paper</button>
        <button type="submit" id="scissors">Scissors</button>
    </div>
```

**//script**

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        let playerSelection = evt.target.getAttribute("id");
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    })
});
```

Also for customs attributes, you can use datasets, so you can extends to whatever you want. The text after "data-" is your data name.

```
   <div id="buttonHolder">
        <button type="submit" id="rock" data-type="rock" data-for-example="eg">Rock</button>
        <button type="submit" id="paper" data-type="paper" data-for-example="eg">Paper</button>
        <button type="submit" id="scissors" data-type="scissors"data-for-example="eg">Scissors</button>
   </div>
```

//script

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        let playerSelection = evt.target.dataset.type; //target is the dom element
        let example = evt.target.dataset.forExample; //for-example become forExample
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    })
});
```

Comment: A good answer should be more than just code. It should explain how it solves the issue, particularly when the answer appears almost identical to existing answers.

Comment: That's a smart approach too. I wish I could accept both answers. Thank you>

Answer (score -1):

example

```html
      <div id="buttonHolder">
        <button type="submit" id="rock" value="rock">Rock</button>
        <button type="submit" id="paper" value="paper">Paper</button>
        <button type="submit" id="scissors" value="scissors">Scissors</button>
      </div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() { // cannot use () => {
        const playerSelection = this.value;
        playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    })
});
```

you cannot use () => in addEventListener callabck because `this.value` will not work

Comment: I remember using it though

Comment: Yes... You can use arrow functions in addEventListener...

Comment: Well either way the button has no value in the first place since it isn't explicitly declared in the beginning... It does however have `.innerHTML` and `.innerText`

Comment: update my answer on why cannot use () =>. there is a different between function() and () => when come to context of the function. when we use () =>, `this` is window object and not the button object itself. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: @rojo while you can use arrow functions as the callback, they **shouldn't** be used in callback functions with dynamic context : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Comment: @JonP Thanks! Either way, since this inside of a `forEach`, OP could just use `button` rather than this.